# VSS 2008 and VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe, directory, reinstall

I'm working on .Net projects using Visual Studio 2008 and Visual SourceSafe 2008.  I'm not very familar with how SourceSafe working folders are tracked.  Due to an unrelated problem, my PC has to be reformatted and I'll have to reinstall SourceSafe.  I currently have a lot of files checked out that I'm working on for a release.  Should I check in all the files, even though they won't build?  Or can I save my local working folders somewhere else and copy them back to the PC after it's formatted?

I did find information on saving the Visual Studio settings by exporting/importing them.  Has anyone tried this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you check in the files to VSS database before reformat, so that you won't lose any changes. You can use Label/Comment to denote the versions. Also, you can [Pin](http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/sourcesafe/pin-in-sourcesafe-vss.html) the previous version which build fine so that when your coworkers perform Get, they will retrieve that version.

Answer (score 0):

When you install vss on your systemm vss comes with Admin interface and client interface first you need to create folder by using Admin software then go to the Visual studio open the project then go to file menu and then the Source control then select  change source control then select all files in your solution then click bind your project will be binded to the VSS if you want to work on any file you need check out first else any changes in project without check out causes lose of data when you close the project ensure that all files are properly checked in so your data will not lost....

hope it helps you thanks